# Hibernate + embedded database - setup

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have created Java application using Hibernate with this configuration:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306     /bee</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <mapping resource="DatabaseMapping.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Everything works fine when Iam using jdbc:mysql://localhost..., but now I need to have the database embedded in my application. Which database should I use? I need to have all my data stored and load it after start the application, update data, save, delete. I use HQL query or SQL query.

What is the simplest way to make the database embedded? I don´t want to change my queries. It would be fine to change only hibernate configuration and set it to the embedded database, is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

One of the advantages of ORM's like Hibernate is to shield you from DB differences. You can use any one of the below as an embedded DB solution. Just change the dialect, driver and URL in hibernate cfg file.

1. [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)
2. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)
3. [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)

Comment: I wasn't able to get Hibernate working with SQLite, which was my first option of database to my next project. Has anyone been able to get that combination working? If so, please post a sequence of steps in order to do so. Meanwhile I'll try to get H2 with Hibernate working. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I understand sqlite is not supported by hibernate anymore. I've spent much time trying to make them work but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Hava a look at using the [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database in embedded mode

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">PUBLIC</property>
    <mapping resource="DatabaseMapping.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your queries, consider mysql-mxj (embedded mysql) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-mxj/en/connector-mxj.html

It is not under active development (thanks Oracle).  But is prefectly usable and the connector is open source.  It is trivial to embed different versions of mysql, but the latest mxj connector embeds 5.5.9

Comment: MariaDB is mysql compatible, there is a project to make it embeddable in a Java project: https://github.com/vorburger/MariaDB4j